# Testing Angularjs using RequireJS using Karma

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, karma-runner

Having trouble in testing angular controller. Im using angular with require js and using karma for testing. Is there any example and github sample.

Comment: How are you using requirejs? Are you loading in all your modules with it, or just some third party dependencies? 

If you post a jsfiddle it will make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a project I created with unit test for RequireJS and AngularJS:

https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD

To run the test, do the following:

```
npm install
grunt test
```

Comment: Thanks @marcoseu. I am also a great fan of reuquirejs with angularjs like you.